# Problem positioning map

Tags: navigation, simulation, mapping, rviz, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem positioning a map. In may Stage is the map good positioned, but in rviz is it totally different, how can I change that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165471/problem-positioning-map/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-05-15**:
Perhaps you just have to change your fixed frame to /map in rviz.

**Comment by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on 2014-05-16**:
I tried, but it's not a solution

**Comment by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) on 2014-05-16**:
You should give more details about what you are trying.  Note that the map in Stage is not really a map in the sense of being some model or reference used by the robot, but rather it is the ground truth used by Stage for simulation, and your robot may not have direct access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using [map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) to publish the map, then you can change the location of the map origin in [the corresponding YAML file](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format).

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on 2014-05-16**:
I'm not using yaml file